# python3, "best/easiest" way to edit audio (.aac in .mp4 .m4a)

Tags: python-3.x, audio

such I am unsure what would be the easiest method to edit/manipulate audio clips in Python 3.  pydub or something ?

The scenario is a slideshow of home phone camera pics interspersed with video clips (usually .mp4 files, .mov files) that are typically less than a couple of minutes but have a hard clipping limit of say 1 minute (so a slideshow video clip may be less duration than source video clip). All video is pre-converted to VFR (audio should be independent of that).

A long-ish background audio is already created as aac in .m4a. A text file exists containing a list of the video clip filenames together with its start_frame_number in the large slideshow video and its duration as a number_of_frames, 1 line per audio.

The challenge is to convert the audio from each clip to .aac (I use ffmpeg to do that bit) and then inject/overwrite the relevant part of it into the large background audio at the start_frame_number for the specific number_of_frames, over-writing whatever audio existed in that place.

So, your recommendations on the best/easiest python tool(s) for activity ?